# SQL Calculate XY distance between two XY Coordinates with one query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database that contains IDs and their associated coordinates.
If I have two ID's what is the most efficient TSQL query that returns the linear distance between these two point?
I know how to do it by using 4 variables and 3 select statements but is there a better way?

```
ID  |  X  |  Y
1   |  10 |  15
2   |  12 |  20
```

Given ID 1 and 2 find the linear distance between them.

Comment: "I know how to do it by using 4 variables and 3 select statements"  can you add this code?  Would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "linear distance", but here is one way to get the Manhattan distance:

```
select abs(p1.x - p2.x) + (abs(p1.y - p2.y)
from points p1 cross join
     points p2
where p1.id = 1 and p2.id = 2;
```

Euclidean distance would use appropriate functions.

Comment: I think I was referring to the Euclidean distance. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Building on GL's code for Euclidean distance:

```
DECLARE @points TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, X DECIMAL(8,4), Y DECIMAL(8,4))

INSERT INTO @points (X,Y) VALUES (10,15),(12,20)
SELECT * FROM @points

SELECT ROUND(SQRT((p1.x-p2.x)*(p1.x-p2.x)+(p1.y-p2.y)*(p1.y-p2.y)),2)
FROM @points p1 CROSS JOIN
     @points p2
WHERE p1.id = 1 AND p2.id = 2;
```

Obviously you have your own code for the table itself, but this will run on its own and you can see that it gives the result of 5.39, rounded because I told it to.

Answer (score 0):

There is handy function you can use

```
DISTANCE(POINT(p1.x, p1.y), POINT(p2.x, p2.y))
```